# Solution to the linear multiplicative heat equation via iteration in the mild formulation.

Tags: partial-differential-equations, convolution, fixed-point-theorems, heat-equation, regularity-theory-of-pdes

Consider the linear multiplicative heat equation on $\mathbb{R}^+\times \mathbb{R}^d$ given by:
\begin{equation}\label{linear multiplicative heat equation}
    \partial_t u= \frac{1}{2}\Delta u + \xi u  \quad (1)
\end{equation}
where the noise $\xi(t,x)$ is supposed to be smooth in time and space, and the initial condition is $u(0,x)=f(x)$ for a function $f$ on $\mathbb{R}^d$.
Denote by $\cdot$ and $\ast$ respectively the convolution in space and in time-space with the heat kernel $K$:
$$K\cdot f(t,x):=\int_{\mathbb{R}^d}f(y)K(t,x-y)dy$$
$$K\ast \xi(t,x):=\int_0^t\int_{\mathbb{R}^d}\xi(s,y)K(t-s,x-y)dyds$$
and let introduce the linear operator $\phi$ defined by: $$\phi:u\mapsto K\ast (\xi u)$$

The *mild* formulation of the equation (1) is the fixed-point equation:
\begin{equation} \label{mild}
    u=K\cdot f + \phi(u)   \quad (2)
\end{equation}

The idea is to get a solution of (1) by expanding the expression (2) iteratively into a serie, that is formally speaking:
\begin{equation}\label{serie}
    \sum_{n=0}^\infty  \phi^{(n)}(K\cdot f)   \quad (3)
\end{equation}

where $\phi^{(0)}=id$, and $\phi^{(n)}$ is the $n$-fold composition.

**Question:** Can we find some nice hypothesis on $\xi$ and $f$ under which the serie (3) is well defined and a solution to the equation (1)?

**Remark:** The sequence of truncated series $u_n:=\sum_{k=0}^n \phi^{(k)}(K\cdot f)$ satisfy the sequence of equations:
$$\partial_t u_n= \frac{1}{2}\Delta u_n + \xi u_{n-1}$$
with initial condition $u_n(0,x)=f(x)$.